# in Anspruch nehmen: to make a physical claim or a figurative claim?

Tags: translation

I thought *in Anspruch nehmen* meant *to use*, *to make a claim on something someone is entitled to*, etc. I.e. all physical actions. Can it also mean making a claim in the sense of *behaupten*, i.e. making an assertion?

[Source](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/rhein-main/frankfurt/nicole-deitelhoff-16669064.html?printPagedArticle=true#pageIndex_2)

> Aber sie **nimmt** für ihre Institution **in Anspruch**, dass sie größere
>   Aufmerksamkeit genießt: „Früher waren wir ein Institut für Kenner;
>   heute sind wir ein Institut, das man kennt.“

It seems the speaker is making an assertion that her institute now enjoys more attention. She is not laying a claim on anything she is entitled to. She is just making a statement.

Is this common use? Wouldn't *behaupten* be better used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonyms *in Anspruch nehmen* and *beanspruchen* can in fact be used figuratively, just like the literal translation of the latter, *to claim*. It is common.

They aren't perfect synonyms of *behaupten*, however, because *behaupten* is very neutral while *in Anspruch nehmen* can have a presumptuous undertone.

Comment: "They aren't perfect synonyms of behaupten, however, because behaupten is very neutral while in Anspruch nehmen can have a presumptuous undertone." It's the other way around. When you say "X behauptet Y" [it implies that you don't believe / aren't convinced that Y is true, i.e. you disagree with X](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/behaupten).

Comment: @Peter your Duden link says something different: *behaupten* means "mit Bestimmtheit aussprechen, überzeugt sagen" – irrespective of the opinion of the speaker. When you say "it's the other way round", do you mean *in Anspruch nehmen* was neutral? It's important to note that **both** expressions are used when the speaker neither wants to confirm nor to deny the validity of what was *behauptet*.

Comment: Yes, I mean "in Anspruch nehmen" is neutral and "behaupten" is not. "(noch Unbewiesenes) als sicher ausgeben" (assert something that has not yet been proven) isn't a neutral statement. It implies disbelief or at least doubt.

Comment: @Peter There's an semicolon between *mit Bestimmtheit aussprechen, überzeugt sagen* and *(noch Unbewiesenes) als sicher ausgeben*, and *noch Unbewiesenes* is obviously bracketed because it is not obligatory that the *Behauptete* is unproved. On the contrary, the [Duden article for *Anspruch*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anspruch) gives the example *etwas für sich in Anspruch nehmen (etwas Bestimmtes von sich behaupten)*. Let the common denominator be that they're synonyms. Furthermore, the rule seems to apply here that there is no accounting for taste and linguistic instinct.